# Edittext focus goes to last edittext in visible edittext on screens

Tags: android, android-widget

I have multiple `LinearLayout` with two `EditText` such that in each `EditText` I have used `android:nextFocusDown` so that when user uses the next button on the softkeypad then focus goes on second `EditText` on same line.

Everything is working well but when the screen is scrolled then the focus goes automatically to the last `EditText` among all visible `EditText` on the screen.

Please give your suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<requestFocus/>` below the first EditText box.